# Compare two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find clients that were enrolled in one program (MMU) and then switched to another (PCHP) between the dates 1/1/2018 and 8/15/2018.  I have the following query that returns clients enrolled in the (MMU) program with a StartDate between two dates.  This works great, however how do I compare this to see if they switched programs?  Currently I have this query.

```
 SELECT c.ULink,
  c.ClientID,
  c.FirstName,
  c.LastName,
  s.LastName AS Staff_LastName,
  s.FirstName AS Staff_FirstName,
  cp1.Description,
  cp.StartDate,
  cp.EndDate
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Client_Program cp ON cp.ClientULink = c.ULink
LEFT JOIN Code_Program cp1 ON cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
LEFT JOIN Staff s ON s.ULink = c.RecordCreatedBy
WHERE cp.ProgramULink = 'MMU') 
  AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open' 
  AND cp.StartDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-08-15'
```

Now I need the same query where ProgramULink = 'PCHP' (but only if they were in MMU). Not sure how to do the logic on this query.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You should think long and hard about your logic. Are you looking for a "switch" that occurred between your dates? If so, MMU is only a concern when it ended between the dates - start date is irrelevant. The opposite is true for PCHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where is killing the left join and you have an extra )

```
 SELECT c.ULink,
  c.ClientID,
  c.FirstName,
  c.LastName,
  s.LastName AS Staff_LastName,
  s.FirstName AS Staff_FirstName,
  cp1.Description,
  cp.StartDate,
  cp.EndDate
FROM Client c
INNER JOIN Client_Program cp ON cp.ClientULink = c.ULink
LEFT  JOIN Code_Program cp1  ON cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
LEFT  JOIN Staff s           ON s.ULink = c.RecordCreatedBy
WHERE cp.ProgramULink = 'MMU' 
  AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open' 
  AND cp.StartDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-08-15' 
  AND EXISTS ( select 1 
               FROM Client c2
               INNER JOIN Client_Program cp2 
                  ON cp2.ClientULink = c.ULink 
                 AND cp2.ProgramULink = 'PCHP'   
                 AND c2.ClientID =  c.ClientID
             )
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to add an INNER JOIN to the Code_Program cp3 table in the EXISTS SELECT query and added a cp2.StartDate >- cp.EndDate and it works perfectly!  Is there a way to show both the cp1.Description AND the cp2.Description values along with both the Start/End Dates from both queries. I'd like to see the dates there were in MMU and then the dates for PCHP.

Comment: @DataCrypt You would do a JOIN rather than and EXISTS.

Comment: Thank you paparazzo.  Any example on using the JOIN rather than EXISTS please.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things nice and simple, I would recommend using a temp table to store the initial result:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#MMU') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MMU
SELECT c.ClientID
INTO #MMU
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Client_Program cp ON cp.ClientULink = c.ULink
LEFT JOIN Code_Program cp1 ON cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
LEFT JOIN Staff s ON s.ULink = c.RecordCreatedBy
WHERE cp.ProgramULink = 'MMU') 
  AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open' 
  AND cp.StartDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-08-15'


 SELECT c.ULink,
  c.ClientID,
  c.FirstName,
  c.LastName,
  s.LastName AS Staff_LastName,
  s.FirstName AS Staff_FirstName,
  cp1.Description,
  cp.StartDate,
  cp.EndDate
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Client_Program cp ON cp.ClientULink = c.ULink
LEFT JOIN Code_Program cp1 ON cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
LEFT JOIN Staff s ON s.ULink = c.RecordCreatedBy
WHERE cp.ProgramULink = 'PCHP') 
  AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open' 
  AND cp.StartDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-08-15'
  AND ClientID IN ( SELECT ClientID FROM #MMU WHERE ClientID IS NOT NULL )
```

This might be a bit easier than other suggestions, depending on your level of experience.

Comment: No need for a temp table for this. Avoid them when you can.

Comment: I didn't state it was needed. I said it was an alternative method, perhaps easier to read or understand for users who have little experience in sql, like the OP. "Avoid them when you can"... That's a bit subjective. Like me telling my co-workers to use CAST instead of CONVERT...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you filter to both programs, you can then use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to find those `ClientID` that had more than one program:

```
SELECT c.ClientID
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Client_Program cp ON cp.ClientULink = c.ULink
LEFT JOIN Code_Program cp1 ON cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
LEFT JOIN Staff s ON s.ULink = c.RecordCreatedBy
WHERE cp.ProgramULink IN ('MMU','PCHP') 
  AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open' 
  AND cp.StartDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-08-15'
GROUP BY c.ClientID
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cp.ProgramULink) > 1
```

You can't include program specific fields in the above, if you want to see the full detail for those that had two you could instead use something like:

```
;with cte as ( SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY c.ClientID) as ct
                      c.ULink,
                      c.ClientID,
                      c.FirstName,
                      c.LastName,
                      s.LastName AS Staff_LastName,
                      s.FirstName AS Staff_FirstName,
                      cp1.Description,
                      cp.StartDate,
                      cp.EndDate
               FROM Client c
               LEFT JOIN Client_Program cp ON cp.ClientULink = c.ULink
               LEFT JOIN Code_Program cp1 ON cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
               LEFT JOIN Staff s ON s.ULink = c.RecordCreatedBy
               WHERE cp.ProgramULink IN ('MMU','PCHP') 
                 AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open' 
                 AND cp.StartDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-08-15'
              )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE ct > 1
ORDER BY ct DESC,ClientID
```

These both assume `ClientID` is the key, if not you can add additional fields to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` or the `PARTITION BY` as needed. The 2nd query would also return instances where someone had more than one record with the same program.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this works, but again, it's hard to do this without seeing sample data.

```
SELECT c.ULink
  FROM Client c
  WHERE c.ULink IN (
    SELECT c.ULink
      FROM Client c
      LEFT JOIN Client_Program cp ON cp.ClientULink = c.ULink
      WHERE cp.ProgramULink = 'MMU' 
        AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open' 
        AND cp.StartDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-08-15'
  ) AND c.ULink IN (
    SELECT c.ULink
      FROM Client c
      LEFT JOIN Client_Program cp ON cp.ClientULink = c.ULink
      WHERE cp.ProgramULink = 'PCHP'
        AND cp.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open' /* unsure about this, maybe you want this closed? */
        AND cp.StartDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-08-15' /* again, edit these checks for finding the other set of users */
  )
```

Basically you're using two subqueries to generate a list of clients that were in MMU, and a list of clients that were in PCHP, and seeing which clients were in both. From there it should be trivial to JOIN against the other tables to fetch the remaining data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.ULink,
  c.ClientID,
  c.FirstName,
  c.LastName,
  s.LastName AS Staff_LastName,
  s.FirstName AS Staff_FirstName,
  cp.Description,
  pchp.StartDate,
  pchp.EndDate
FROM Client c 
INNER JOIN Client_Program mmu ON mmu.ClientULink = c.ULink 
    AND mmu.ProgramULink = 'MMU' AND mmu.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open'
INNER JOIN Client_Program pchp ON pchp.ProgramULink = 'PCHP'
    AND pchp.ClientULink = mmu.ClientULink AND pchp.ProgramStatusULink = 'Open'
    AND pchp.StartDate BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20180815'
LEFT JOIN Code_Program cp ON cp.ULink = pchp.ProgramULink
LEFT JOIN Staff s ON s.ULink = c.RecordCreatedBy
WHERE mmu.StartDate < pchp.StartDate
```